# How do I avoid this erasure error in Java?

Tags: java, generics, collections, erasure

I have a homemade storage object that is similar to `Set interface` methods.  I want to make it compatible with `Set` so it can be compatible with `Collection`s.   The problem is that it is a generic class and that generic class uses the type variable as method parameters.

The two methods I am talking about:

I have:

```
remove(T var) {/*remove var*/}
```

`Set interface` has this:

```
remove(Object var) {/*remove var*/}
```

The compiler tells me that there is some kind of *erasure error*.  I can change `remove` from `remove(T var)` what it is to removing`(Object var)` but I prefer not to do that.

Is there another way to do this that would make it compatible with `Set` without changing my original method signature?

Comment: The method in `Collection` is `remove(Object)` (it wasn't in the first attempt to generify collections, but there are good reasons for it to be there). If you want `remove(T)` you'll need to not implement `Collection`, or implement `Collection` and duplicate `remove` under a different name.

Comment: You will find it much easier to add a `toSet()` method to your class, than to directly implement Set.  Implementing Set is about more than just filling in methods defined by the interface;  you have to return an Iterator whose `remove` method removes elements from your collection, and you have to implement set equality in your `equals` method.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's declared as `(Object v)` and not `(T v)` is because it removes all objects `x` where `v.equals(x) == true`. Please note that objects of different classes can be compared with each other and it's perfectly legal for them to be equal, because `equals` does not require objects to be of the same class.